# SQL Server STpointfromText comes from PHP into javascript as garbage

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, sql-server, php, well-known-text

Sorry for the sloppy title.
Here's the scenario - I have a table in `SQL Server 2008 R2`
It has a geographyColumn, created thusly:

```
add geographyColumn as geography::STPointFromText('POINT('+convert(varchar(20),x_coord)+'     
'+convert(varchar(20),y_coord)+')',4326)
```

When I viewed it in the table, it looks fine:

```
POINT (-116.477654 33.764695)
```

I have some javascript, and a PHP script, to grab points from said table. I can get any text field without a problem. But I want to get the X,Y vales from the geography column.  Instead of a nicely formed "X,Y" or even a long string of numbers, I get this mess:

```
����zU���f�C@
```

My php is the following:

```
<?php $q=$_GET["q"]; 
$serverName = "ServerIP"; 
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"geo_spat2", "UID"=>"u", "PWD"=>"p"); 
$con = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo); 
if (!$con){ 
   die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true)); 
}; 
$sql="SELECT * FROM EMPTY_REPS WHERE Division_label = '".$q."'"; 
$result = sqlsrv_query($con, $sql); 
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) { 
  echo $row['geographyColumn'] . ", "; 
} 
sqlsrv_close($con); 
?>
```

Am I missing something simple?
Thanks,
Evan

Comment: The problem could be in your PHP, or in your JavaScript.

Comment: The PHP is pretty simple:
    <?php
 $q=$_GET["q"];
 
 $serverName = "ServerIP";
 $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"geo_spat2", "UID"=>"u", "PWD"=>"p");
 $con = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

 if (!$con){
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
   };
 
 $sql="SELECT * FROM EMPTY_REPS WHERE Division_label = '".$q."'";
 $result = sqlsrv_query($con, $sql);
 while($row =  sqlsrv_fetch_array($result))
   {
   echo $row['geographyColumn'] . ", ";
   }
   
 sqlsrv_close($con);
?>

Comment: Your PHP is simply selecting the geography column from the row. In PostGIS, the geometry column does not store WKT text - it stores a hex hash of the WKB representation. SQLServer probably does the same thing, but displays the WKT when you view the table.

Comment: OK, how do I get the actual record out of it/\

Comment: Ok, how do I get the actual records?

echo $row['rep_no'] . ", ";
echo $row['NAME'] . ", ";

both work fine,  I get the actual record. what am I missing?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest adding another varchar column for WKT and returning that column in your PHP. You can do an update statement and use `STAsText()` to set the WKT column.

```
UPDATE myTable
SET WKT = geographyColumn.STAsText();
```

Comment: Or just add 'SELECT * , geographyColumn.STAsText() as WKT FROM ...' , WKB geography can also be quite big i some cases so best idea is use 'SELECT c1, c3, geographyColumn.STAsText() as WKT FROM ...' Or if you still want to use 'SELECT * ...' create view

Answer (score 0):

You can access the coordinate data using [`STX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933828%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) and [`STY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933990%28v=sql.100%29.aspx):

```
DECLARE @g geometry;
SET @g = geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT(-116.477654 33.764695)', 4326);
SELECT @g.STY AS Latitude, @g.STX AS Longitude;
```